# Console output and file output seem to be different

Tags: java

So I am doing this program where I go through every folder in the designated folder and if there are any files inside of thoes folder, I read them.

The files look like this:

```
file name: grades

Mait 5 5 5
Kati 3 3 3
Vello 4 4 4
```

So I read in each line and the 0th element in every line is the name of student which I add into an array. After that I take the grades and then calculate the median of them.

Also the files are in folders that are named by a class name. For instance math has every math grade in it.

Now the programs job is to read all thoes files and then produce a output file that contains every students name and their median in every class and after that the median of all their grades.

This is how my output looks right now:

```
Nimi: Mait Keskmine hinne: 5.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Kati Keskmine hinne: 3.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Vello Keskmine hinne: 4.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Mait Keskmine hinne: 1.0 Aine: ..\text\students\math\grades
Nimi: Kati Keskmine hinne: 2.0 Aine: ..\text\students\math\grades
```

It's not in english but its in the form of name:, median; , class name;

Now the problem here is that, when I print the same thing out to console, instead of a file I get this:

```
Nimi: Mait Keskmine hinne: 5.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Kati Keskmine hinne: 3.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Vello Keskmine hinne: 4.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Mait Keskmine hinne: 5.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Kati Keskmine hinne: 3.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Vello Keskmine hinne: 4.0 Aine: ..\text\students\english\grades
Nimi: Mait Keskmine hinne: 1.0 Aine: ..\text\students\math\grades
Nimi: Kati Keskmine hinne: 2.0 Aine: ..\text\students\math\grades
```

Now as you can see, the first file that is read, is duplicated or something for some reason. This problem does not occur when I only have one folder from which the program can read from. But it does for more folders.

Now why is this a problem for me? Because I cannot see how I could manage to calculate the median of all the grades that one student has gotten in school, when I have duplicate values in my program.

What might be the issue here and how can I solve it?

Here are all my classes in the project so you guys could see the code:

Main.java:

```
package files;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Path lessons = Paths.get("../text/students");
        FileVisitor file = new FileVisitor();
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(lessons, file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Path> files = file.askFiles();
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Path adress:files){
            //System.out.println(adress.getFileName());
            try {
                BufferedReader textIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(adress.toString()));
                String line;
                while((line = textIn.readLine()) != null){
                    String[] readContent = line.split(" ");
                    Student student = new Student(readContent[0],adress.toString());
                    //System.out.println("sad");
                    for(int i = 1;i < readContent.length; i++){
                        student.addGrade(readContent[i]);
                        //System.out.println(adress.getParent()+ " ");
                    }
                    students.add(student);
                }
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("../text/opilased_out"));
                for(Student i:students){
                    output.println("Nimi: "+i.askName() + " " + "Keskmine hinne: "+i.askMedian() + " " + "Aine: "+i.askSubject());
                    System.out.println("Nimi: "+i.askName() + " " + "Keskmine hinne: "+i.askMedian() + " " + "Aine: "+i.askSubject());
                }
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }   
        }
    }
}
```

Student.java:

```
package files;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {
    String studentName;
    List<Integer> studentGrades = new ArrayList<>();
    String subjectName;
    double sum;

    public Student(String name, String subject) {
        subjectName = subject;
        studentName = name;
    }

    public String askSubject(){
        return subjectName;
    }

    public String askName(){
        return studentName;
    }


    public void addGrade(String grade) {
        studentGrades.add(Integer.parseInt(grade));
        //System.out.println(studentGrades);
        for (int i = 0;i < studentGrades.size(); i++){
            //System.out.println(studentGrades.get(i));
        }
    }

    public double askMedian() {
        double median = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < studentGrades.size(); i++){
            //System.out.println(studentGrades.get(i));
            median += studentGrades.get(i);
            sum = median/studentGrades.size();
        }
        //System.out.println(studentGrades);
        //System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

FileVisitor.java:

```
package files;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    private List<Path> adresses = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc)
            throws IOException {
        return super.postVisitDirectory(dir, exc);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException {
        return super.preVisitDirectory(dir, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException {
        adresses.add(file);
        //System.out.println(file);
        return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc)
            throws IOException {
        return super.visitFileFailed(file, exc);
    }

    public List<Path> askFiles(){
        return adresses;
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Have been trying to figure out the problem for days now...

Comment: That does not answer your question but since you are using Java 7, why not use try-with-resource statements and `Files`?

Comment: Just a question - Did you run with a Debugger(with IDE?)

Comment: Yes, I use Eclipse to run it.   And to fge, I am simply not familiar with that option yet.

Comment: See [here](http://fgaliegue.blogspot.com/2014/03/working-with-files-java-6-versus-java-7.html), this should get your started with `Files`

Comment: Allright, thanks!  Will read it through.

Comment: Any ideas about the problem it self?

Comment: I got the duplicate thing fixed, seems I had created a total mess there with thoes try's and catches. Also moved the output loop a bit down. Now it's fixed.